# How to load Firebase data to Graph Entity? Is there a way to modal the data? With Swift 3

Tags: cosmicmind

I'm new to CosmicMind and have questions about the data process.

In the CosmicMind CardTableView Sample, the data are read from SampleData of Entity type.

Q1: Is there a way I can load my Firebase Data to Entity? And if so, how to do it? Looks like shouldn't be difficult, as it's JSON already. I'm using Swift 3.2

Q2: Is there a way to modal the Entity?

Thanks a lot!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Welcome to CosmicMind :)

The easiest way would be to create an import function that takes in your JSON data and maps the key value pairs to properties in an Entity. If there is a type specifier in Firebase, then you can set that as the Entity type. I don't use Firebase, so I can't describe the setup 100%, but here is an example of what you would do, assuming Firebase gives you a unique ID.

```
func importFirebase(data: [[String: Any]]) {
    let graph = Graph()
    let search = Search<Entity>(graph: graph).for(types: "User")
    let users = search.sync()
    var index = [Int: Entity]()

    for user in users {
        if let id = user["id"] as? Int {
            index[id] = user
        }
    }

    for json in data {
        if let id = json["id"] as? Int {
            var entity: Entity

            if nil == index[id] {
                entity = Entity(type: "User")
            } else {
                entity = index[id]!
            }

            for (k, v) in json {
                entity[k] = v
            }
        }
    }

    graph.sync()
}

let data = [
    ["type": "User", "id": 1, "name": "Daniel", "age": 33],
    ["type": "User", "id": 2, "name": "Adam", "age": 28],
    ["type": "User", "id": 3, "name": "Sarah", "age": 23]
]

importFirebase(data: data)
```

This is not necessarily the optimal solution, it should give you an idea though.

Hope it helps, all the best!

Comment: Thank you for your reply. Not sure still, but will try.

Comment: What are you not sure about?

Comment: This way seems like very loose coupling. I use data modal with my Firebase data. From the Snapshot, I got the key value pairs, then I map them to my data modelling. I still don't know how to map these Graph Entity properties with my data modal class.

Comment: So the issue is taking the values from an Entity to Firebase?

Comment: Yes, both ways. Currently, I have data model layer, read from and write to Firebase. I'm not sure where and how to add the Entity to my current data model layer.

Here is an example of my data:
class User {
    var uid: String?
    var name: String?    
    init(snapshot: FIRDataSnapshot) {
        self.uid = snapshot.key
        if let resources = snapshot.value as? [String : AnyObject] {            
            if let name = resources["name"] as? String {
                self.name = name
            } else {
                self.name = ""
            }
    }
}

Comment: Sorry for the poor formatting. And thank you for your help!

Comment: I am not that familiar with Firebase. So I can't be much help with that. My assumption would be that you would need to write an exporting function, like the importing one, which adds he Entity values to Firebase models and then syncs.

Comment: Hi, thank you for your patience and help. I just realized I asked a silly question. I can just use my Firebase Model Object as the Data, I don't have to use Entity from Graph. Thanks again!

Comment: is there any example of how to use your own data models and not use entity? I am able to load my data into a table view, but not able to see how to port it over easily to CardTableView without using Entity and Graph...

Comment: Well the example is to demonstrate how to use a data-driven approach to updating a `TableView`. This is what `Graph` makes possible. Using your own models in this case would require that you have the same `data/event - driven` approach. You can use a `NSFetchController` or something similar as well.